# Mirth: Mapper: Cannot get data to map to variables

Tags: mirth

I'm learning Mirth and ran into a weird issue.

I created an HL7 to HL7 channel.  I can get the v2.3 hl7 messages into the source and out of/to the destination. no problem.  But when i set up a mapper step in the transformer to map data to a variable the data from the message will not copy over to the variable. Variable is just blank

variable name: patDOB2
mapping:       msg['PID']['PID.7']['PID.7.1'].toString()

i used the same message for inbound and outbound templates and used that message for testing

MSH|^~&|AccMgr|1|||20050110045504||ADT^A01|599102|P|2.3|||
EVN|A01|20050110045502|||||
PID|1||10006579^^^1^MRN^1||DUCK^DONALD^D||19241010|M||1|111 DUCK ST^^FOWL^CA^999990000^^M|1|8885551212|8885551212|1|2||40007716^^^AccMgr^VN^1|123121234|||||||||||NO NK1|1|DUCK^HUEY|SO|3583 DUCK RD^^FOWL^CA^999990000|8885552222||Y||||||||||||||
PV1|1|I|PREOP^101^1^1^^^S|3|||37^DISNEY^WALT^^^^^^AccMgr^^^^CI|||01||||1|||37^DISNEY^WALT^^^^^^AccMgr^^^^CI|2|40007716^^^AccMgr^VN|4|||||||||||||||||||1||G|||20050110045253||||||
GT1|1|8291|DUCK^DONALD^D||111^DUCKST^^FOWL^CA^999990000|8885551212||19241010|M||1|123121234||||#Cartoon Ducks Inc|111^DUCK ST^^FOWL^CA^999990000|8885551212||PT|
DG1|1|I9|71596^OSTEOARTHROS NOS-L/LEG ^I9|OSTEOARTHROS NOS-L/LEG ||A| IN1|1|MEDICARE|3|MEDICARE|||||||Cartoon Ducks Inc|19891001|||4|DUCK^DONALD^D|1|19241010|111^DUCK ST^^FOWL^CA^999990000|||||||||||||||||123121234A||||||PT|M|111 DUCK ST^^FOWL^CA^999990000|||||8291
IN2|1||123121234|Cartoon Ducks Inc|||123121234A|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||8885551212
IN1|2|NON-PRIMARY|9|MEDICAL MUTUAL CALIF.|PO BOX 94776^^HOLLYWOOD^CA^441414776||8003621279|PUBSUMB|||Cartoon Ducks Inc||||7|DUCK^DONALD^D|1|19241010|111 DUCK ST^^FOWL^CA^999990000|||||||||||||||||056269770||||||PT|M|111^DUCK ST^^FOWL^CA^999990000|||||8291
IN2|2||123121234|Cartoon Ducks Inc||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||8885551212
IN1|3|SELF PAY|1|SELF PAY|||||||||||5||1

I have tried it as every kind of map: global channel, channel, etc
I have tried it in an iterator
I have tried it with different mappings within "msg"
I have tired it with all the above using tmp
I must be doing something very very wrong or missing some very simple step because i have literally followed along with 4 different tutorials and still it is not working.

I can get static data like "dog" or mirth generated data like a timestamp or uuid into the variable but not data from the msg or tmp.

I actually broke down and made the HL7 to HL7 channel to test this problem because on a HL7 to JSON channel the data from the msg segments was not copying over to the JSON file BUT timestamp, UUID, and static data would.

if needed i can attach a copy of the transformer or channel. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To aid assistance, kindly share the Channel, a raw source file and a desired template of the output file to aid assistance or a screenshot of the message builder or Javascript transformer code you are using to assign variables.